# Como limpar os dados da tela?

Tags: php, javascript, html

*Gostaria de saber como chamar a mesma tela só que com os campos vazios!*

Ou seja, a mesma tela só que do inicio, sem as informações que o usuário informou!

Exemplo dos campos: [Campos](http://jsfiddle.net/939P7/1/)

Comment: Por favor, publique o código aqui. As perguntas devem ser completas e o Fiddle usado somente para demonstrações.

Answer (score 4):

Com javascript utilize

```
var form = document.getElementById('form');
form.reset();
```

Isso vai apagar os valores dos campos inputs, campos com valor padrão serão mantidos. Outra solução é usar um input reset no form.

```
<input type="reset">
```

Answer (score 1):

eu uso uma function no javascrip em que eu passo o link da pagina que esta o formulario. ex.:

```
function limpar(){
    self.location = "./meusite.php?a=sda232";
}
```

dai chamo a function atraves do onclick do button