# Tem como executar um reset ao acessar a página?

Tags: html

Gostaria de saber se tem como executar o `<input type="reset">` quando se acessa uma página, sem precisar clicar em algum botão!

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22677/?

Comment: @bfavaretto♦ já havia visto dessa forma, mas não teve o resultado que eu esperava!

Comment: Não? E qual foi o resultado?

Answer (score 1):

Vai ter q usar js ou jquery, tem várias formas de fazer isso.

```
$(function() {
   $('#id_do_form')[0].reset();
   //ou
   $('#id_do_form').trigger("reset");
});
```

Tem vários outros meios.

Answer (score 0):

Pode tentar utilizar a função **window.onload** para fazer isto.

**JS**

```
window.onload = function (){
  document.getElementById("FormId").reset();
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#FormId').reset();
});
```